# Rails 4, nested attributes, Couldn't find Tag with ID= for Person with ID=

Tags: nested, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Rails 4:
I want to create Person with tags

```
person = Person.new(:name=>Jon', :tags_attributes=>[{:id=>'15', :name=>'some_tag'}])
```

My Person model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :organizations, through: :people_organizations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, join_table: :people_tags

  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :emails, as: :emaileable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :networks, as: :networkable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :messengers, as: :messengerable, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, :emails, :networks, :messengers, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, reject_if: :all_blank

end
```

My PeopleController:

```
  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save(validate: false)
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:id, :name, :born, :description, 
      phones_attributes:[:id, :number, :_destroy],
      emails_attributes:[:id, :email, :_destroy]
      networks_attributes:[:id, :name, :_destroy],
      messengers_attributes:[:id, :identifier, :_destroy],
      tags_attributes:[:id, :name, :_destroy]
    )
  end
```

When i create new person, i have error

```
p = Person.new(:name=>'Jon', :tags_attributes=>[{:id=>'15', :name=>'tag'}])
```

> Couldn't find Tag with ID=15 for Person with ID=

Please tell me what to do to keep the model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RAILS: Nested attributes in new method with existing record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355956/rails-nested-attributes-in-new-method-with-existing-record)

Comment: There's an answer to the same question over here, which involves overwriting the `tags_attributes=` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355956/rails-nested-attributes-in-new-method-with-existing-record

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. I think that rails just don't support creating a new record with an existing nested record. I found no solution for this situation at all.
So Try to filter tags_attributes from person_params and then use tag_ids like this:

```
tag_ids = params[:person][:tags_attributes].map { |tag| tag[:id] }
@person = Person.new(person_params.merge({ tag_ids: tag_ids })
```

Comment: Seems like someone create a gist for a similar problem: https://gist.github.com/mfazekas/c13d76b027ca3ee6923e#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: FWIW, the solution in the gist didn't work for me but the solution in this answer did

Answer (score 0):

You should create the nested fields through of `people_tags` relationship, for example something like that

```
= form_for(@person) do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
 
  = f.simple_fields_for :people_tags do |people_tag_builder|
    people_tag_builder.hidden_field :tag_id 15
    
    = people_tag_builder.simple_fields_for :tags, user do |tag_builder|
      = tag_builder.id 15
      = tag_builder.text_field :name, value: 'tag'
```

the `people_tag_builder.hidden_field :tag_id 15` is mandatory because it the middle table needs either `person_id` or `tag_id` how you are creating a person, you must send a tag object or create it or both