# RAILS: Nested attributes in new method with existing record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have models:

**Frame.rb**

```
belongs_to :manufacturer, foreign_key: 'model'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :manufacturer, :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj.blank? }
```

When i try to create new Frame with existing manufacturer i get an error:

```
Frame.new({name: 'Name of the frame', manufacturer_attributes: {id:2}})
```

**Error:**

```
Couldn't find Manufacturer with ID=2 for Frame with ID=
```

Comment: Does the manufacturer with an id of 2 exist?

Comment: Just try commenting out :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj.blank? } part of the accepts_nested_attributes

Comment: @dane, It makes no sens but i already did that

Comment: @Src please provide result for `Manufacturer.where(id: 2)`

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `Frame.new` is a new record, when ActiveRecord reaches the parameter `manufacturers_attributes` it performs a lookup on the association `manufacturers_attributes` for `Frame.new` which is unsaved and hence has no id with which to perform the lookup.

I recommend starting with the existing `manufacturer` record and simply create the frame like so `manufacturer.frames.create(frame_params)` (assuming a one-to-many relationship).

However, if you must do it this way you can overwrite the `manufacturer_attributes` method like so:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :manufacturer
  def manufacturer_attributes=(attributes)
    if attributes['id'].present?
      self.manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(attributes['id'])
    end
    super
  end
```

Thus, you assign the manufacturer before the original `manufacturer_attributes` tries to access it on the new record, which previously caused the error.

Comment: What if you have multiple manufacturer attributes some existing and some not?

Answer (score 9):

If you want a new Frame with an existing manufacturer you need to assign it in the params as well as using nested attributes.

```
Frame.new({name: 'Name', manufacturer_ids: [2], manufacturer_attributes: {id:2}})
```

The new Frame now has the assigned Manufacturer so when it attempts to update the Manufacturer with the `manufacturer_attributes` it can find it correctly.

If you only want to assign the existing Manufacturer and not update any attributes then you don't need the `manufacturer_attributes`.

Comment: This works fine and is the right answer really, except `manufacturer_attributes` is not even needed. If you aren't attempting to create new associated records and specifically only want to create a parent pre-associated with _existing_ other records, all you need is `manufacturer_ids` and do _not need_ to accept-nested-attributes-for.