# Rails 4 and change in behavior when associating existing nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm upgrading from rails 3.2 to 4.0. I noticed there is a big change in the behavior when using ActiveRecord to associate an existing child model to a new Parent model.

Consider de following:

```
class Parent
  has_many :kids
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids
end

class Kid
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

and the following context:

```
Kid {id: 1, name: 'kid1', parent_id: nil}
Kid {id: 2, name: 'kid2', parent_id: nil}
```

If I send this parameters to the controller:

```
"parent"=>{ "title"=>"mom", "kids_attributes"=>{ "1"=>{"id"=>"1", "name"=> "kiddo"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"2"} }
```

And do:

```
p = Parent.new(params[:parent])
p.save
```

With Rails 3.2 the result is:

```
Parent {id: 1, title: 'mom'}
Kid {id: 1, name: 'kiddo', parent_id: 1}
Kid {id: 2, name: 'kid2', parent_id: 1}
```

But, with Rails 4.0 (after converting to strong_parameters) the call to `Parent.new` raises an error

```
Couldn't find Kid with ID=1 for Parent with ID=
```

[I read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355956/rails-nested-attributes-in-new-method-with-existing-record/37356422)

It seems now I have to create the Parent first and then save the children.

This is a problem in the cases I may have existing and non existing children being submitted at the same time. I would have to manually check which children already exist (have and id), remove them from the parameters, save the parent, and then update their attributes ?

Is this what I have to do in order to upgrade Rails or there is something else causing this different behavior ?

In fact, when I do

```
@parent = Parent.new
@parent.kids.build(parent_parameters[:kids_attributes])
```

ActiveRecord do no lookups and the Kids remain with only the id set. In my context I cannot save any of the records yet.

Comment: The problem is more likely how your form is structured. If you use `fields_for` its smart enough to know which records are persisted and not and only will add the hidden id input for persisted records.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

1. Only pass id attributes for when updating a child
2. And never pass id attributes for when creating a new child

For example if you want update `kid1` and create a new child with name `kid2` send parameters to controller like:

```
"parent"=>{ "title"=>"mom", "kids_attributes"=>{ "1"=>{"id"=>"1", "name"=> "kiddo"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"kid2"} }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mehedi. But I am already submitting like this and the `Parent.new` method is not accepting `id` inside kids_attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I read this [thread][2]

So, now if you need to associate existing record you have to submit attributes likes this:

```
"parent"=>{ "title"=>"mom", "kid_ids"=> ["1", "2"] }
```

And if you need to create/update new/associated records you submit the attributes in the regular fashion:

```
"parent"=>{ "title"=>"mom", "kids_attributes"=>{ "1"=>{"name"=> "kiddo"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"1","name"=>"boy"} }
```

In order to do the first I had to use this in the form

```
<%= check_box_tag "parent[kid_ids][]", parent.kids.include?(kid) %>
```

And to accept these parameters

```
params.require(:parent).permit( { :kid_ids => [] } )
```

I did not accept this answer because this method seems to be a lot less flexible. What I would do if I had to associate existing records and at the same time update already associated ones ? I would have to handle those separately ?